# When are $n!+1$ and $(n+2)!+1$ coprime?

Tags: number-theory, factorial, gcd-and-lcm, python

For every $n\geq 1$, $n!+1$ and $(n+1)!+1$ are coprime. I suspected the same would happen for $n!+1$ and $(n+2)!+1$, but short Python script yielded 3 counterexamples:

- $\gcd(7!+1,9!+1)=71$
- $\gcd(16!+1,18!+1)=61$
- $\gcd(61!+1,63!+1)=71$

But up to $n=30000$ it finds no more counterexamples.

So it could be that $7$, $16$ and $61$ are the only ones or that Python is hallucinating (does it really handle numbers as large as $30000!$?).

Which is it?

---

**Edit:** as discussed in the comment section,
$$\gcd(n!+1,(n+2)!+1) = \gcd(n!+1,n^2+3n+1).$$
So considering $n^2+3n+1$ instead of $(n+2)!+1$ might simplify the problem.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150524/discussion-on-question-by-luca-t-castrillon-when-are-n1-and-n21-copr); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 7):

As to the mathematical question: we are looking for $n$ such that $n! + 1$ and $n^2 + 3n + 1$ are both divisible by an odd prime $p$.  Of course $p > n$.
The roots of $x^2 + 3x + 1$ are $(-3 \pm \sqrt{5})/2$, so $5$ must be a square mod $p$, which says (if $p > 5$) $p \equiv 1$ or $4 \mod 5$.  These are asymptotically about half of all primes. For such $p$, there are two values of $n \in [0, \ldots,p-1]$ which make $n^2 + 3n + 1$ divisible by $p$.

Heuristically the probability that $n!+1$ is also divisible by $p$ is about $1/p$.
So since the sum of $1/p$ for primes $p$ diverges, we should expect there to be infinitely many counterexamples.  However,
since the sum diverges very slowly, it may be very difficult to
find more of those counterexamples.

Comment: Actually $p>n+3$.

Comment: "The roots of $x^2 + 3x + 1$ are $(-3 \pm \sqrt{5})/2$, so $5$ must be a square mod $p$, which says (if $p > 5$) $p \equiv 1$ or $4 \mod 5$." Can you elaborate on how this 
is derived or point somewhere where I can find out more about it. Thanks.

Comment: @LucaT.Castrillón If your'e getting nitty gritty $p > n+4$ as well.

Comment: @OlderAmateur [Quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity): $5$ (which is a prime $\equiv 1 \mod 4$) is a quadratic residue modulo odd prime $p$ if and only if $p$ is a quadratic residue mod $5$.  The quadratic residues mod $5$ are $0, 1, 4$.