# Deriving modular properties of factors of a polynomial based on the roots of the polynomial.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

This is from an answer by Robert to this question [When are $n!+1$ and $(n+2)!+1$ coprime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4832101/when-are-n1-and-n21-coprime/4832170#comment10288571_4832170)

"The roots of $x^2 + 3x + 1$ are $(-3 \pm \sqrt{5})/2$, so $5$ must be a square mod $p$, which says (if $p > 5$) $p \equiv 1$ or $4 \mod 5$."

Can anyone elaborate on how this is derived or point me somewhere where I can read up on it. Thanks.

Comment: There are three assertions in a row in that quote; which one is the "this" you want information on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the discriminant of the binary quadratic form $u^2 + 3uv + v^2$  is $9-4=5$

If we have (positive) prime $q$   with Legendre symbol $(5|q) = -1$  and
$q | u^2 + 3uv + v^2, \; \; $  then both $q | u$ and $q | v.$ Thus, no such prime $q$  can divide  any $x^2 + 3x + 1.$   The number $x^2 + 3x + 1$  may be divisible by $5$  and it may be divisible by primes $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 5$

background material includes the Legendre symbol and quadratic reciprocity. Here, we used $(q|5) = (5|q) $   because $5 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$

Comment: same thing. Except for $2$ itself, primes are odd,  so $1,4 \pmod 5$   refer to $1,9 \pmod{10}$